# ejb remote client giving EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling error

Tags: ejb-3.0, wildfly

I am getting an error while running a remote client for EJB3 and wildfly.
My ejb looks something like bellow.

```
    package com.tst.ejb;

    import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;

    /**
     * Session Bean implementation class TestWLDFly
     */
    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class TestWLDFly implements TestWLDFlyRemote {

        /**
         * Default constructor. 
         */
        public TestWLDFly() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void TestPrint() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
  }
```

Remote interface is as follows

package com.tst.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

```
@Remote
public interface TestWLDFlyRemote {

    public void TestPrint();
}
```

Remote client is as bellow...

```
package com.tst.ejb;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.jboss.ejb.client.ContextSelector;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientConfiguration;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration;
import org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector;

public class EJBClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

            final Hashtable<String, Object> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();

            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
            p.put("remote.connections", "one");
            p.put("remote.connection.one.port", "8080");
            p.put("remote.connection.one.host", "localhost");

            EJBClientConfiguration cc = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(p);
            ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> selector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(cc);
            EJBClientContext.setSelector(selector);

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext(props);


            final String rcal = "ejb:/TSTWLDFLY/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFlyRemote";
            final TestWLDFlyRemote remote = (TestWLDFlyRemote) context.lookup(rcal);

            remote.TestPrint();


    }

}
```

Wildfly log shows JNDI names as bellow

```
java:global/TSTWLDFLY/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFlyRemote
java:app/TSTWLDFLY/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFlyRemote
java:module/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFlyRemote
java:jboss/exported/TSTWLDFLY/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFlyRemote
java:global/TSTWLDFLY/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFly
java:app/TSTWLDFLY/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFly
java:module/TestWLDFly!com.tst.ejb.TestWLDFly
```

I am getting an exception I run the client.

```
Nov 19, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 2.1.1.Final
Nov 19, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
Nov 19, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
Nov 19, 2015 4:46:36 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
Nov 19, 2015 4:46:41 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector setupEJBReceivers
WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to localhost:8080
java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:94)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:80)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:158)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:115)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:47)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:279)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:289)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TestPrint(Unknown Source)
    at com.tst.ejb.EJBClient.main(EJBClient.java:40)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:TSTWLDFLY, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@5c5a1b69
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:774)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TestPrint(Unknown Source)
    at com.tst.ejb.EJBClient.main(EJBClient.java:40)
```

I tried all the JNDI names. May be I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `@LocalBean` annotation. It makes impossible remote access to this EJB. Just remove it.

Comment: Thanks sibnick. The error still exist. No luck. I am using wildfly 9.x